# Application launch bar and menu not showing apps

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

I have got lubuntu 15.

I was having an issue with new desktop files not being picked up by the lxde menu. I followed instructions on here -> http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Main_Menu#Refreshing_the_Menu and since then, the menu has stayed empty. Also, if I try to add an application to a launch bar, the list of applications to add is empty.

Lxpanectl restart or kill all lxpanel;lxpanel does not fix it.

If I log out and log in as Lubuntu notebook profile, run kill all lxpanel;lxpanel then the menu is populated with applications. However,the application launch bar still has no "installed applications".

All the desktop files are where they should be.

Any ideas/advice? Even how to just refresh back to default settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install gnome-panel`  solves my problem.